# How to export to other format with the materials

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I'm making a *Transparent Glass Cup* in Blender 2.8

I'm using the **Principled BSDF** --> **Transmission set to 1, Roughness set to 0**

If I'm not mistaken, if I export it to *.obj*/*.fbx* file, the glass cup will no longer transparent and I will need a texture for it to make it transparent again.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You would need to bake the alpha transparency into a new texture. Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/86891

Answer (score 1):

What you should export out is a 'Transparency Map'. Otherwise known as Alpha Map as well

Its a black & white map, where black means 0(fully transparent), white means 1 (fully opaque)

After preparing a transparency map, you can connect it to the transparency/alpha slot in any engine, and it would work the same.